# Did Jasmine Tridevil have a third breast added surgically?

Tags: beauty, body-modification

Right now, [various](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2014/09/22/jasmine-tridevil-surgery-third-breast-total-recall-style_n_5859776.html) [news](https://www.ad.nl/ad/nl/1014/Bizar/article/detail/3752374/2014/09/22/Vrouw-laat-derde-borst-implanteren.dhtml) [sites](https://www.bild.de/news/ausland/brust-operation/us-amerikanerin-hat-drei-brueste-37724000.bild.html) are running an item about a woman calling herself Jasmine Tridevil, who supposedly has had a third breast implanted, resembling a character from the movie *Total Recall*.

Is this true, or are the pictures photoshopped and is it a hoax?

[image: A selfie of Jasmine Tridevil, showing her three breasts]

Comment: From the huff story "Tridevil’s bold new look is of course reminiscent of that infamous scene from the **1999** Arnold Schwarzenegger film Total Recall." I weep.. I weep hard. Im guessing whoever wrote that story was probably in nappies when the Arnie one *really* came out

Comment: http://www.snopes.com/photos/bodymods/jasminetridevil.asp Inconclusive, but inconsistencies that make it likely to be a hoax.

Comment: Snopes has since updated, and says "False"

Comment: "Total Recall"? I first thought of The Triple-Breasted Whore of Eroticon Six - here's a [SFW] link to a BBS linking to a [2012 photo of said Eccentrica Gallumbits cosplay](http://h2g2.com/user/U40285/conversation/view/F10027/T8295040/page/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Prosthesis

A Google search finds several different pictures of Jasmine Tridevil, which suggests it is not a case of a simple photoshopping of one image.

At least one reporter claims to have [interviewed](http://www.wtsp.com/story/news/local/2014/09/22/tampa-woman-claims-to-add-3rd-breast/16083847/) Jasmine Tridevil.

There are some reports ([1](http://www.nydailynews.com/life-style/florida-woman-breast-hoax-article-1.1949712), [2](http://www.viralglobalnews.com/entertainment/jasmine-tridevil-woman-three-breasts-fake/17588/)) that suggest Jasmine Tridevil is using a prosthesis

> Alisha Jasmine Hessler, once filed a complaint under that name with
>   the airport in Tampa, FL. Among the stolen items was a “three breast
>   prothesis[sic].”

Comment: there is a video from her site on YouTube where the color of the prosthesis is clearly paler and ashier than the rest of her skin.